# clicking using selenium python but no response

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

[I chose the xpath from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6CYk.jpg)

[This is the button I am trying to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SrQ9.jpg)

```
add =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/main/div/section[4]/section/section[2]/section[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div')
add.click()
print("hey")
```

This is the code, add.click() does not generate any error and hey is printed but the button is not clicked..

Initially the add button is not in the viewport but when the code executes it automatically comes in the view port but nothing happens.

I have tried doing everything like scroll to element, and brought the element in the viewpoet but still nothing happens..

This is from where I got the xpath

```
<div class="sc-1usozeh-8 kTTqJP">

  <span class="sc-1usozeh-6 fTsfFl">Add</span>

  <i class="rbbb40-1 MxLSp sc-1usozeh-4 TZpZK" size="14" color="#ED5A6B">.
 
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ED5A6B" width="14"    
     height="14" viewBox="0 0 20 20" aria-labelledby="icon-svg-title-  
     icon-svg-desc-" role="img" class="rbbb40-0 hoSSCx">
 
      <title>plus</title>

      <path d="M15.5 9.42h-4.5v-4.5c0-0.56-0.44-1-1-1s-1 0.44-1 1v4.5h-
      4.5c-0.56 0-1 0.44-1 1s0.44 1 1 1h4.5v4.5c0 0.54 0.44 1 1 1s1-0.46 
      1-1v-4.5h4.5c0.56 0 1-0.46 1-1s-0.44-1-1-1z"></path>

   </svg>
 </i>
</div>
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML expanding the `<i>` element.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add']/.."))).click()
```

If above doesn't work try

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add']")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)


action = ActionChains(driver)

action.move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

You need to import action class:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: 1st answer does nothing. 2nd answer causes exception selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: Is the button visible on the screen ?

Comment: yes the button is visible... This is the page.  https://www.zomato.com/mumbai/mcdonalds-dadar-west/order

Comment: Visible inside the view port ? Means you don't have to scroll to that button ?

Comment: I have to scroll to the button.

Comment: Could you try and let me know

Comment: Still shows the same error. apparently the scroll into view scrolls beyond the element

Answer (score 1):

The element is a dynamic element, so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

As a last resort you can use `execute_script()` as follows:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add']"))))
```

Comment: the button is still not responding.

Comment: @SahilGogia Are you able to locate the button with the xpath through devTools/console?

Comment: yes I can.. Using inspect element and I copy the xpath

Comment: @SahilGogia Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: A JavaScript exception occured: null is not an object (evaluating 'arguments[0].click') is generated

Comment: I am trying to automate zomato's website so this a button you press to enter food in your cart..

Comment: @NicLaforge Thanx for the edit. Nice catch :)